# print the name of macro identifier associated with integer with variable

Tags: c

I cannot find something similar to this.

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

int main()
{
   int x = ONE;
   printf("%s \n", x);
}
//the desirable output will be "ONE"
```

Now, I saw the other answers with the

```
#define PRINT(X) printf("%s \n", #x);
```

and I did not find how to use it to get what I want.

Comment: Aren't you defining ONE to be 1? So you could say x = ONE; and it would be the same as what you are doing right now?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? How about reading the documentation of `printf`? If that does not help, maybe you miss some of the basics of the language. The code above invokes undefined behaviour, iow: it is not valid C.

Comment: `//the excepted output will be "ONE"` Are you sure about this? Did you try that?

Comment: @matt you are right i corrected it.

Comment: What behavior do you want for `int x=ONE + ONE;`?

Comment: @Olaf what i want is to print the name of the #define statement witthout it name. and with a variable which holds the value. i'v not see somthing like this.

Comment: @chtz just to print it, to console, file etc.

Comment: @Nati.E: As I assumed: you missed basics of C and programming in general. There is no connection between the macro `ONE` and the `int` variable. No offence. but **please** get a book about programming in general and C specifically.

Comment: @Olaf I thank you for taking my question seriously, but please see the answer I'd marked, HolyBlackCat answer.

Comment: @Nati.E: This approach is awful and nothing you should use in larger production code. Also the approahc defines an `enum`, not an `int` as you ask in your question. My comment above stands.

Comment: @Olaf, Ok so please give some clear solution.

Comment: @Olaf Saying "awful approach" is not constructive.

Comment: @Nati.E: It depends on what you want to accomplish!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Not really. Such code is hard to maintain and debug. Depending on what OP wants, automatically generated code or other approaches are much better fits.

Comment: @Olaf As I mentioned all I need is to print it to file\console.

Comment: @Nati.E: That is not what I mean. See ^

Comment: @Olaf As far as I understand, OP wants to have a list of named constants, and the ability to convert a value (of any expression) to the name of the corresponding constant. (Since that's what my answer does, and OP seems to like it.)

Comment: @Olaf: Enumeration constants are of type `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I did not speak about the constants. `int x` is `int`, for an `enum` the compiler can choose a smaller type for the actual implementation (and e.g. AAPCS takes advantage of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KeithThompson said, there is no easy way.

But there is a [clever hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) which does more or less what you ask for.

```
#define MY_ENUM_LIST \
    X( ONE   , 1 ) \
    X( TWO   , 2 ) \
    X( THREE , 3 )

#define X(name, value) name = value,
enum MyEnum {MY_ENUM_LIST};
#undef X

const char *my_enum_to_str(enum MyEnum e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        #define X(name, value) case value: return #name;
        MY_ENUM_LIST
        #undef X
      default:
        return "<invalid>";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = ONE;
    printf("%d\n", x); // prints "1"
    printf("%s\n", my_enum_to_str(x)); // prints "ONE"

    return 0;
}
```

It has following advantages over the naïve lookup table:

- No need to repeat enumerator names twice.
- You can have any enumerator values, not only a contiguous range.
- You can't accidentaly assign an incorrect name to an enumerator.

Comment: That is an awful approach.

Comment: @Olaf Please elaborate. Saying "awful approach" is not constructive at all. AFAIK it's the best existing solution. The only alternatives are simple lookup tables (which require duplicating enumerator names, often leading to bugs) and looking up enumerator values by their names at runtime, which is obviously slow. The only downside of this approach is that the syntax is pretty exotic.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Debugging, maintenance are two aspects.

Comment: @Olaf My point is that any other solution (apart from code generation, which would work nicely) would require one of the two things: 1. Duplicating names of those enumerators. And there is *no way* you will know that you've accidentaly desynchronized those lists, until you start to get weird name/value mismatches. Isn't it harder to maintain the two lists than only one?

Comment: 2. Looking up enumerator values at runtime, using something like `int get_value(const char *)`, which is not only slow, but also lacks compile-time detection of invalid names, which also makes debugging/maintaining harder. Thus, I'm very interested in seeing more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to do this. The only information you have in your `printf` call is a variable `x` whose current value happens to be `1` (at run time), which happens to be the expansion of a macro whose name is `ONE`. There is no way for the compiler to figure out the name `ONE` from that information. There might be several different macros with the same definition, or there might not be any.

If you want to print the string `ONE` given the integer value `1`, you're going to have to set up some kind of lookup table or function. For example:

```
const char *const names[] = { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", /* etc. */ };
printf("%s\n", names[x]);
```

It would be entirely up to you to get the names right, so that for example `1` doesn't map to `"THREE"`.

Comment: thank you, great solution!! but to call that it make me work hard. the answer of @HolyBlackCat is better for me. THANK YOU!

Comment: I'd make the array `const`, too.